# How can I show a thumbnail popover like iBooks on iOS?

Tags: ios, thumbnails, uipopovercontroller, ibooks

This popover is shown when dragging across the bottom bar on fixed layout epubs. It is not a normal UIPopover (the borders are different). It looks more like a UIMenuController, but one cannot put images in those. How can this be done?

[image: iBooks thumbnail popover]

Comment: You can customize the background of a UIPopover using the new appearance APIs, or you can just create an entirely custom UIView that looks like a popover.